# material_ui table component not rerender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wrote a component and use table in it and then I use that component inside other component but when I change the props value in parent component the table component not re render :
use state below in parent component :

```
const [focusedField,setFocusedField] = useState ('insuranceType')

useEffect(() => {
    const keypress = e => {
        if(e.key == "Enter" ){
            setChange(true)
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keypress", keypress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", keypress);
    };
}, []);
React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(change){
        if(focusedField == "insuranceType" ){setFocusedField("tests")}
        if(focusedField == "tests" ){setFocusedField("calculateTestCosts")}
        if(focusedField == "calculateTestCosts" ){setFocusedField("nationalId")}
        if(focusedField == "nationalId" ){setFocusedField("patientName")}
        if(focusedField == "patientName" ){setFocusedField("patientSurname")}
        setChange(false)
    }
},[change])
```

then :

```
           <InlineTable formValues={formValues} setFormValues={setFormValues} tableContent={tableContent} setTableContent={setTableContent} focusedField={focusedField}/>
```

I solve the problem by using state in return and use setTimeout :

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    if(focusedField === "tests"){
        setDisplay(false)
        setTimeout(()=>{setDisplay(true)},20)
    }
},[focusedField])

return (
    display && 
    <TableContainer> 
            <TableBody>
                {tableContent.map((row,index) => (
                        <TableCell style={{width : "20%" , paddingRight : 1 , paddingLeft : 0}}>
                            <Autocomplete
                                id="tests"
                                name="tests"
                                options={["1" , "2"]}
                                value={row?.codeName}
                                onChange={(e,newValue)=>handleOnChange(newValue,`codeName`,index)}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={<p style={{fontSize : "10px"}}>کد-نام تست</p>}  
                                autoFocus={focusedField == "tests" ? true  : false}
                                inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, tabIndex: 2}}
                                />}
                        /></TableCell>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
```

but I think it is not right way to solve problem
can any one help me ?

Comment: Did you add the `display` state as part of your fix? When you say it doesn't rerender do you mean it doesn't reflect the updated value of `focusedField`? If you provide a little more info about the problem, and the existing (not working) code it may help to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: yes, I fixed problem by adding display but I think it is not correct way , and yes the value of focusedField not update , I edit the code and add more about codes

Comment: I added key attribute to table and solve my problem